# AS3 Platformer Slope Detection

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, collision

i am in the process of making a platformer in AS3. However, one thing im struggling with is how to manage slope detection. Preferably id like something similar to that of games like *fancy pants adventures*, but id really prefer not to use an external thing such as Box2D or CDK, because both of which confuse me greatly, and id generally prefer just to not have one. All my attempts have had the problem that i can get it to work with some slopes but not all (e.g character manages up one slope, but falls through the other) then when i change it to suit the other, it doesnt suit the first one (e.g player manages the second slope, but bounces up and down crazily on the second...
So, any help would be greatly appreciated...
Thanks.
Code is as follows.

```
//var setup
var leftPressed: Boolean = false;
var rightPressed: Boolean = false;
var upPressed: Boolean = false;
var downPressed: Boolean = false;
var leftBumping: Boolean = false;
var rightBumping: Boolean = false;
var upBumping: Boolean = false;
var downBumping: Boolean = false;
var lowerleftBumping: Boolean = false;
var lowerrightBumping: Boolean = false;
var leftBumpPoint: Point = new Point(-30, -87);
var rightBumpPoint: Point = new Point(30, -87);
var lowerleftBumpPoint: Point = new Point(-32, -2);
var lowerrightBumpPoint: Point = new Point(32, -2);
var upBumpPoint: Point = new Point(0, -174);
var downBumpPoint: Point = new Point(0, 0);
var scrollX: Number = -4;
var scrollY: Number = -68;
var ySpeed: Number = 0;
var xSpeed: Number = 0;
var speedConstant: int = 5;
var maxSpeedConstant: Number = 30;
var frictionConstant: Number = 0.9;
var gravityConstant: Number = 2;
var jumpConstant: Number = -45;
//game
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function keyDownHandler(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = true;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = true;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = true;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = false;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = false;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = false;

    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = false;
    }
}

function loop(e: Event): void {
    if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("leftBumping");
        leftBumping = true;
    } else {
        leftBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("rightBumping");
        rightBumping = true;
    } else {
        rightBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("upBumping");
        upBumping = true;
    } else {
        upBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("downBumping");
        downBumping = true;
    } else {
        downBumping = false;
    }
            if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + lowerleftBumpPoint.x, player.y + lowerleftBumpPoint.y, true)) {
            trace("lowerrightBumping");
            lowerleftBumping = true;
        } else {
            lowerleftBumping = false;
        }
        if (back.hitTestPoint(player.x + lowerrightBumpPoint.x, player.y + lowerrightBumpPoint.y, true)) {
            trace("lowerrightBumping");
            lowerrightBumping = true;
        } else {
            lowerrightBumping = false;
        }
    if (leftPressed) {
        xSpeed -= speedConstant;

    } else if (rightPressed) {
        xSpeed += speedConstant;

    }
    if (leftBumping) {
        if (xSpeed < 0) {
            xSpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (rightBumping) {
        if (xSpeed > 0) {
            xSpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (upBumping) {
        if (ySpeed < 0) {
            ySpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (downBumping) {
        if (ySpeed > 0) {
            ySpeed = 0; //set the y speed to zero
        }
        if (upPressed) {
            ySpeed = jumpConstant;
        }
    } else {
        ySpeed += gravityConstant;
    }
    if (xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant) { //moving right
        xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
    } else if (xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)) { //moving left
        xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
    }
    xSpeed *= frictionConstant;
    ySpeed *= frictionConstant;
    if (Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5) {
        xSpeed = 0;
    }

    scrollX -= xSpeed;
    scrollY -= ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;
    if (scrollY < -770) {
        scrollX = -4;
        scrollY = -68;
        ySpeed=0
        xSpeed=0
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You should express your exact problem and show the piece of code that causes the problem.

Comment: There are online tutorials (yes, there are plenty) how to make platformer games, even step-by-step tutorials, you should have started with those in the first place. If Box2D, which is there exactly to make things easier and to wrap the confusing collision and reverse kinematics part confuse you, do you really expect to get out of it with easier and simpler solution by not using it?

Answer (score 1):

If I was forced to not use the love of my life (Box2D) then I suppose I would play around with [hitTestObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) and do some math on the angle of any of my slopes to generate the rate at which they would move to start. This question is a bit broad and I think the community here is more for specific problems and not architecture brainstorming.

Comment: Hi, I perfectly understand what your saying here, my question is a bit broad, and I know they don't work well here. I would love to use Box2D, but there is nothing I can find on the internet that seems to explain how to use it when your game isn't contained within a class. This is rather irritating, because I keep having projects obstructed by this problem. However, if you'd be willing to explain/ walk me through this, then I'd be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: Frame code isn't efficient. I'd seriously advise you break out of your design like that as building large applications using that method will make you spend a lot more time on it than you would on a normal project with classes. It's really not that hard and learning that will open you up to a lot more in Flash/AIR... The best way I can put it is if you were to only have 1 frame and put all of your code on there with no children having any frame code and build up like that..but that's a horrible practice and you should *seriously* consider the other way instead.

Comment: Well, again, I have no idea how to do that, because that is just 100% out of my knowledge... Like, I've used classes before, but those were difficult, and I encountered dozens of problems, and had to import loads of stuff... I'll try though. If I get it working can I rely on advice about Box2D from you?

Comment: Not me specifically no. You can come back to this community if you run into any trouble at any time with a specific bug in your learning ventures.

Comment: Please note: I am part of the community :). I will say though that I haven't touched box2d since I was in middle/highschool so any guides you find at the moment might be more on point than me. I may be rusty on a few elements but everyone here can always lend you a hand.